# Check intersection of Segment_2 from Gmpq kernel with a Circle in CGAL

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal

**Edit2:** I have redefined my entire setup as the following:

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_circular_kernel_2 CircK;
typedef CGAL::Point_2<CircK> Point_2;
typedef CGAL::Segment_2<CircK> Segment_2;
typedef CGAL::Circle_2<CircK> Circle_2;
```

I still can't seem to find the proper function to do the intersection however... CGAL's examples mostly involve `Circle_2` and `Line_2` or just two circles.

Comment: [This example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Circular_kernel_2/Circular_kernel_2_2intersecting_arcs_8cpp-example.html) should help. Just replace the circular arc type by the line and it should be fine.